# Springdoc Swagger 3 - Failed to load API definition after adding API Group

Tags: spring-boot, springdoc, springdoc-openapi-ui

I have a Spring boot application that works perfectly fine with Springdoc until I add the following code to group the endpoints into a default group.

```java
    @Bean
    public GroupedOpenApi hideApis() {
        return GroupedOpenApi.builder().group("default")
                .pathsToExclude("/api/v2/**", "/v2/**")
                .pathsToMatch("/api/v1/**", "/v1/**")
                .addOperationCustomizer(new customCustomizer())
                .build();
    }
```

As soon as this part of code is added I'm getting the below error

[image: Failed to load Api Definition - Fetch error]

Any idea what is wrong?

Springdoc v1.4.3

Spring-boot 2.x

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Cause by a Null Pointer Exception in the OperationCustomizer class, i.e in the `customCustomizer()` of the given code.